# how to get new vertex coordinates of a rectangular block after applying glRotate()

Tags: c++, opengl

I am drawing a rectangular block:

```
GLfloat cubeVertexV[] = {
    // FRONT
    -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.5f,
     0.5f, -1.0f,  0.5f,
    -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.5f,
     0.5f,  1.0f,  0.5f,
    // BACK
    -0.5f, -1.0f,  -0.5f,
     0.5f, -1.0f,  -0.5f,
    -0.5f,  1.0f,  -0.5f,
     0.5f,  1.0f,  -0.5f,
    // LEFT
    -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.5f,
    -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.5f,
    -0.5f, -1.0f, -0.5f,
    -0.5f,  1.0f, -0.5f,
    // RIGHT
     0.5f, -1.0f, -0.5f,
     0.5f,  1.0f, -0.5f,
     0.5f, -1.0f,  0.5f,
     0.5f,  1.0f,  0.5f,
    // TOP
    -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.5f,
     0.5f,  1.0f,  0.5f,
     -0.5f,  1.0f, -0.5f,
     0.5f,  1.0f, -0.5f,
    // BOTTOM
    -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.5f,
    -0.5f, -1.0f, -0.5f,
     0.5f, -1.0f,  0.5f,
     0.5f, -1.0f, -0.5f,
};
```

Now I apply `glRotate()` in x, y, and z axes on this block. Now I want to change the `cubeVertex` array with the new coordinates resulting from the application of `glRotate` call. Is this possible in OpenGL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, OpenGL will just accumulate the transforms, and only actually apply them to the data when you render it. In the plain old fixed-function graphics pipeline, there's no way to do it. However, as programmability has been increasing every generation, there is support for this now via OpenGL extensions, provided you're using a recent enough graphics card. Whether you have an nVidia or ATI card might also make a difference, as they don't always support the same extensions.

It's been some time since I did much OpenGL, so this is going to be a little vague, but the general idea is:

- you bind a pair of Vertex Buffer Objects,
- put your data in the first one,
- use Transform Feedback to render the transformed vertices into the second,
- and you can then read back data from the second VBO into memory.

The nVidia Transform Feedback Fractal demo on their [OpenGL Code Samples](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10/opengl/samples.html) page should help you with the actual code for this.

If you want to do more general math on your GPU, you should look into [GPGPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPGPU) techniques, there's a LOT more stuff you can do, and with CUDA / OpenCL / etc. it gets a lot easier to code, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `glGet` with `GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX` to get the current modelview matrix (assuming you applied the `glRotate` call to it). Then, manually transform your vertices by the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

It's not trivial, but look up `glRenderMode(GL_FEEDBACK);` to get started. This will give you not only the coordinates, but also (for example) colors after lighting has been applied.